# Firebase FCM background notifications click_action

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to navigate to a specific screen route when i click on the background notification
for now the default behavior is just launching my app, so how and where do i change the default behavior of the click action

i'm sending the notification using cloud functions, here is the code

```
const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
  notification: {
    title: doc["senderName"],
    body: doc["msg"],
    sound: "default",
    badge: "1",
  },
  data: {
    type: "chat",
  },
};
return fcm
  .sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
```

somehow i want to access the type **"chat"** so from there i can navigate to a chat screen

Answer (score 0):

Use [onMessageOpenedApp](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessageOpenedApp.html) to handle when a user presses a notification. `RemoteMessage` has [data](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage/data.html) property which holds the custom parameters.

Comment: but isn't the background messages handled by the onBackgroundMessage ?

Comment: onMessageOpenedApp  isn't called when i tap the notification @user18309290

Answer (score 0):

- When you click on the **notification from background** state, `onMessageOpened` stream function is called.

Initialize this stream function in the initState of first page of the app and **check the data in payload** you received from the notification just like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {

      if (message != null) {
            String screenName = message.data['screenName'];
            print("Screen name is: $screenName");

            if (screenName == 'chat') {
                    //Navigate to your chat screen here
                 }
       }
    });
```